# Prevent double code execution from HTTP and Timer activated functions

Tags: c#, azure, function, webjob

I have a function which checks every 5 minutes if there are any entries in my database that need to be handled. In this table I have an attribute "Ishandled" to keep track of which entries have already been handled.

Now I have a second function which is triggered through HTTP. This functions allows me to immediately handle a certain entry from the database, by passing along the ID of the entry.

My question is. If I activate my second function at the same time as when the 5 minute timer activates, is it possible for this specific entry to be handled twice?
If so, how can this be prevented? I was thinking to have a single instance running of the webjob and use a lock on both functions, but from experience I know that locks are not quite efficient.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems your timer trigger and http trigger are both try to do something about the entries in the database. So you can have a logic in your http trigger to have a check of the 'Ishandled' attribute, only when the entry was not be handled then you get in the logic to handle the entry.

Comment: This is basically what I implemented, however even when you check whether it has not been handled yet, right after that check, the time trigger can also fire, do the same check and therefor both handle the same entry.